# Trying to evaluate integral$\int_0^\infty x \sqrt{1-e^{-x}}\,e^{-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrating
$$
\int_0^\infty  x \sqrt{1-e^{-x}}\,e^{-x}dx\equiv I
$$
but cannot get the answer, I would like a proof not a numerical answer.  My attempt at proof: 
$$
y=\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}\\
y(0)=0, \ y(\infty)=1\\
y^2=1-e^{-x}\\
2ydy=e^{-x}dx\\
e^{-x}=1-y^2\\
x=\ln\frac{1}{1-y^2} \rightarrow\\
I=2\int_0^1 y^2\ln\frac{1}{1-y^2} dy=\\
-2\int_0^1y^2\ln(1-y^2)\,dy=\\2\int_0^1y^2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{y^{2k}}{k}=\\
2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\int_0^1 y^{2(k+1)}dy=\\
2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(3+2k)}=\\
2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{3k}-\frac{2}{3(2k+3)}    \right)
$$
but this diverges because $\sum_k\frac{1}{k}\to\infty$?  Mistakes I made...

Please help if can on doing the sum or integral. Thank you, Grazie

Comment: Tip: maybe an $y=e^{-x}$ substitution?

Comment: You computations are correct, and the sum does converge by the comparison test: $0 < \frac{1}{k(3+2k)} < \frac{1}{2k^2}$.

Comment: @heropup thank you.  How can calculate sum though?  I am having problem doing this

Comment: Maple 18.01 outputs ${\frac {16}{9}}-4/3\,\ln  \left( 2 \right)  $. I like $$evalf(Int(x*sqrt(1-exp(-x))*exp(-x), x = 0 .. infinity), 20)= 0.85358153703118403189$$ more.

Comment: @user64494 Yes i noticed this also but How can prove it?  I am trying to prove cant you see my attempt at the proof I posted?

Comment: No, your sum does not diverge, since it is [alternating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test). And since the [alternating harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Related_series) converges to $\ln2$, it should come as no surprise then that yours also converges to a similar expression, $\dfrac43\bigg(\dfrac43-\ln2\bigg)$.

Comment: @Lucian okay how can calculate the sum though?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

Comment: For the last step, you it boils down to computing $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{2k} - \frac{2}{2k+3}\right)$. Try to compute the sum up to $N$, and then let $N$ go to $\infty$ once you have found the closed-form expression.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{2k} - \sum_{k=1}{N} \frac{2}{2k+3} = \frac{1}{N} - 2 + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( \frac{1}{2k} - \frac{1}{2k+1} \right) = \frac{1}{N} - 2 + \sum_{k=2}^{2N-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}
$$
which goes to $-2+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} = -1 - \log 2$

Comment: Sorry, there were a couple typos.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{2k} - \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2k+3} = 
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{2k} - \sum_{k=2}^{N+1} \frac{1}{2k+1} = 
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2N+3} + \sum_{k=2}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right) = 
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2N+3} + \sum_{k=4}^{2N+1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}
$$
and this goes to $\frac{1}{2}+1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\ln 2=\frac{4}{3}-\ln 2$. It only remains to (re)multiply by $2\cdot 2\cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{4}{3}$ to get $I=\frac{16}{9} - \frac{4}{3}\ln 2$.

Comment: @user1111 I tried to add an answer which covers the topic in detail and using simple arguments, hope it can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue with your method too. Use partial fraction decomposition this way:
$$\frac{4}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+3}\right)=\frac{4}{3}\int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(x^{2k-1}-x^{2k+2}\right)\,dx=\frac{4}{3}\int_0^1 \,dx\left(\frac{1}{x}-x^2\right)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{2k}$$
where I used the following two:
$$\int_0^1 x^{2k-1}\,dx=\frac{1}{2k}$$
$$\int_0^1 x^{2k+2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2k+3}$$
Since $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{2k}=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$, you get:
$$\frac{4}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^3}{x}\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\,dx=\frac{4}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{(x^2+x+1)x}{1+x}\,dx=\frac{4}{3}\int_0^1\left(x+\frac{x^3}{1+x}\right)\,dx$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}\int_0^1 \left(x+\frac{x^3+1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\,dx=\frac{4}{3}\int_0^1 \left( x^2+1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\,dx=\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}-\ln 2\right)$$
$\blacksquare$

Comment: This is magic......I had to check it as the answer, thanks for going with what I had started

Comment: @user1111: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 9):

An elementary closed-form antiderivative is obtainable.  Integration by parts with the choice $u = x$, $du = dx$, $dv = \sqrt{1-e^{-x}} e^{-x} \, dx$, $v = \frac{2}{3}(1-e^{-x})^{3/2}$ yields $$F(x) = \int u \, dv = \frac{2x}{3} (1-e^{-x})^{3/2} - \frac{2}{3} \int (1-e^{-x})^{3/2} \, dx.$$  This suggests a trigonometric substitution of the form $e^{-x} = \cos^2 t$, or $x = -2 \log \cos t$, and $dx = 2 \tan t \, dt$:  $$\begin{align*} \int (1-e^{-x})^{3/2} \, dx &= \int (1-\cos^2 t)^{3/2} \cdot 2 \tan t \, dt \\ &= 2\int \sin^3 t \tan t \, dt \\ &= 2 \int (1-\cos^2 t)^2 \sec t \, dt \\ &= 2 \int \sec t - \cos t - \sin^2 t \cos t \, dt. \end{align*}$$  This latter integral can be easily evaluated term by term using known formulas, which I leave to you.

Comment: Interesting; I would have made the substitution first, and *then* recognized partial fractions as the standard way to deal with the resulting logarithm.

Answer (score 5):

By partial integration we have
$$
\int x \sqrt{1-e^{-x}}e^{-x}dx = \frac{2}{3} x (1-e^{-x})^{3/2} -\frac{2}{3}\int dx (1-e^{-x})^{3/2}
$$
now by letting $y=e^{-x}$, $-\ln y =x$, $dx = -dy / y$ we have
$$
\int dx (1-e^{-x})^{3/2} = \int \frac{-dy}{y}(1-y)^{3/2}
$$
now let $\sqrt{1-y} = \tau$, $y= 1-\tau^2$, $dy = -2\tau d \tau$ so
$$
\int \frac{+2\tau d \tau}{1-\tau^2}\tau^3 = 2\int d\tau \frac{\tau^4-\tau^2+\tau^2-1+1}{1-\tau^2} = -2 \int \tau^2 d\tau - 2\int d\tau +2\int \frac{d\tau}{1-\tau^2}=\\
-\frac{2\tau^3}{3}-2\tau +  \ln \frac{1+\tau}{1-\tau}.
$$
We have to put everything back together in orderly fashion:
$$
\frac{2}{3}x(1-e^{-x})^{3/2}-\frac{2}{3}\left[-\frac{2}{3}(1-e^{-x})^{3/2}-2\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}+\ln \frac{1+\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}}{1-\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}}\right].
$$
Now, as $x\to 0$, the primitive approaches $0$. As $x\to \infty$ we have to handle an indeterminate form:
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left[\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}}{1-\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}}-x(1-e^{-x})^{3/2}\right]=\\
=\lim_{y\to 0}\left[\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-y}}{1-\sqrt{1-y}}+\ln y \cdot (1-y)^{3/2}\right]=\\
=\lim_{y\to 0}\left[\ln\frac{1+1-y/2}{1-1+y/2}+\ln y \cdot (1-3y/2)\right] =\lim_{y\to 0}\ln\frac{(2-y/2)y}{y/2} = \ln 4.
$$ 
If we have done everything right our result is:
$$
\frac{2}{3}(-\ln 4+2+\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{2}{9}(8-3\ln 4).
$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Following the ${\large\tt OP}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x\root{1 - \expo{-x}}\expo{-x}\,\dd x&=
2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k\pars{3 + 2k}}
=\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + 5/2}\pars{k + 1}}
\\[3mm]&={\Psi\pars{5/2} - \Psi\pars{1} \over 5/2 - 1}
={2 \over 3}\bracks{\Psi\pars{5 \over 2} - \Psi\pars{1}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.1}}$.

> Also
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{\infty}x\root{1 - \expo{-x}}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
> ={2 \over 3}\bracks{\Psi\pars{3 \over 2} + {2 \over 3} - \Psi\pars{1}}
> ={2 \over 3}\bracks{\Psi\pars{1 \over 2} + {8 \over 3} - \Psi\pars{1}}
> $$
>   where [we used](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.2}}$ and ${\bf\mbox{6.3.5}}$.

However
$$
\Psi\pars{\half}=-\gamma - 2\ln\pars{2}\,,
\qquad\Psi\pars{1} = -\gamma 
$$
$\ds{\gamma}$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.3}}$.
$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}x\root{1 - \expo{-x}}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
={16 \over 9} - {4 \over 3}\,\ln\pars{2}} \approx 0.8536
$$

Answer (score 3):

Using the well-Known Series formula for the Digammafunction http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function we have $$2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(2n+3)}=\frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{2}-1}{(n+1)(n+\frac{5}{2})}=\frac{2}{3}(\gamma +\psi(\frac{5}{2}))$$

Recall the recurrence relation formula for Digamma, i.e $$\psi(x+1)=\psi(x)+\frac{1}{x}$$ hence it reduces to $$\frac{2}{3}(\gamma +\frac{8}{3}+\psi(\frac{1}{2}))$$ It is pretty simple to calculate that $\psi(\frac{1}{2})=-\gamma -2\log2$ So your sum finally evaluates to $$\frac{2}{3}(\frac{8}{3}-2\log2)=\frac{4}{3}(\frac{4}{3}-\log2)$$

Answer (score 2):

Your sum doesn't diverge:

$$ \left(\frac{1}{3k} - \frac{2}{3(2k+3)} \right) 
= \frac{(2k+3) - (2k)}{3k(2k+3)}
= \frac{3}{3k(2k+3)}$$

so its convergence behaves like $\frac{1}{2k^2}$, not like $\frac{1}{3k}$.

However, there's an easy approach to working from the point where you introduced the sum: you can simplify the logarithm by using $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$.

Comment: I do not understand this line "However, there's an easy approach to working from the point where you introduced the sum: you can simplify the logarithm by using....$\log(ab)=\log a +\log b$".  How to use this identity though?  Everything else makes lot of sense to me, is great! But you can help with that one question?

Comment: $1-y^2=(1-y)(1+y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x\sqrt{\vphantom{^1}1-e^{-x}}\,e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int_0^1\log(u)\sqrt{1-u}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{1}\\
&=-\frac23\int_0^1\log(u)\,\mathrm{d}\left(1-\sqrt{1-u}^3\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\frac23\int_0^1\frac{1-\sqrt{1-u}^3}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{3}\\
&=\frac43\int_0^1\frac{1-v^3}{1-v^2}v\,\mathrm{d}v\tag{4}\\
&=\frac43\int_0^1\left(v^2+1-\frac1{v+1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}v\tag{5}\\
&=\frac43\left(\frac43-\log(2)\right)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $u=e^{-x}$
$(2)$: $\frac23\mathrm{d}\left(1-\sqrt{1-u}^3\right)=\sqrt{1-u}\,\mathrm{d}u$
$(3)$: integrate by parts
$(4)$: substitute $v=\sqrt{1-u}$
$(5)$: polynomial division
$(6)$: integration